# Compare a user input to a list python3

Tags: python-3.x

Hey guys so I tried looking at previous questions but they dont answer it like my teacher wants it to be answered. Basically i need to get a string from a user input and see if it has:
 at least one of [!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,)] (non-letter and nonnumeric
character)
o Create a list for these special characters

I have no idea how to make a def to do this. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look into [Regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Regular expressions allow you to do many string operations in a concise way. Specifically, you'll want to use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) in order to find all special characters in your string and return them. You can check if the returned list has length 0 to check if there were any special characters at all.

With regards to building the regular expression to find special characters itself... I'm sure you can figure that part out ;)

Comment: Okay so I tried using findall and the if statement that uses just ignores it now. This is what i did   ' def containsSpecial(password):
 specialChar = ['!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')']
 if re.findall(specialChar, password)
  return "true"'

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below

```
import re
inputstring = raw_input("Enter String: ")
print inputstring
print "Valid" if re.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$", inputstring) else "Invalid"
```